# Use bootstrap css and other global css in Vue.js custom elements

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3, shadow-dom, custom-element

No fancy webpack, simple Vue custom element with some global css and some inline css for overrides.

I would like to use some styling library, like from getbootstrap.com and have it change styles inside custom element.

https://jsfiddle.net/Deele/6xk1atrn/25/

```html
<div class="btn bg-info">Zero</div>
<test-widget id="One"></test-widget>
<test-widget id="Two"></test-widget>
```

```js
const TestWidget = Vue.defineCustomElement({
  props: {
    id: String
  },
  data: () => {
    return {
        message: 'Test'
    }
  },
  emits: {},
  template: `<div class="btn bg-info">{{id}} {{message}}</div>`,
  styles: [`div { color: green; }`]
})

customElements.define('test-widget', TestWidget)
```

```css
.bg-info {
  background-color: red!important;
}
```

Was expecting divs inside rendered elements would be styled as buttons, but it does not work!?

From what I have found in the internet, it has something to do with Shadow DOM not inheriting any global styles.

Please, tell me if there is a solution to this approach? I would like to create small widgets for my website using Vue.js, but this hurdle creates fatal limitation.

Comment: Can you compile your vue? This doesn't seem to happen when I try this using single file components.

Comment: After doing some reading about this it looks like your options are use SFC or import your global styles in your styles array. Like this https://jsfiddle.net/nogztqb1/

Comment: @bassxzero Sure, that is an option, I even found more convoluted ways, how to import all CSS files from parent document into this widget. My question is - if we have 10 different imports like that, doesn't it create a substantial overhead on browser, importing same thing, again and again?

Comment: it probably does create a decent amount of overhead. It also seems like a nightmare to maintain. It would probably just use SFC and compile my vuejs to get around all of this if i were you.

Comment: @bassxzero Please, create a separate answer to the question with same widget created as single file component, and how such could be ran inside a non-vuejs application.

Comment: Do not use shadowDOM is the easiest answer

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman ok, how? Trick question, can't use VueJS without Shadow DOM, thus, your solution is to not use VueJS at all? :)

Comment: It's called a framework for a reason. Your Web Component should not be a whole application. If you have decent vanilla JS skills it shouldn't take you much longer than using Vue. And your time investment comes with benefits; no upgrade issues for the next 25 JavaScript years. And your native Web Component will run in any other framework without the Vue overhead.

Comment: BTW Your component will not use all of Bootstrap. So why not **copy** the required Bootstrap parts into your component. Again, maybe some extra hours work, but no dependencies for the next 25 HTML5 years (and a way smaller footprint)

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I think that it is inappropriate to debate use of chosen technology in general in this question, but to digress, here is what Vue has to say about "Web Components vs. Vue Components" https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/web-components.html#web-components-vs-vue-components and imho, it is meaningful to use Vue for complex JS applications or widgets rather than vanilla JS, as it is much easier to maintain and its parts to transfer to other projects and reuse, and handle performance issues.

Comment: @Deele, web components are designed to be opaque to context styling. Their use-case is aimed at the advertisement industry, to provide confidence the ads cannot be tempered with by host website. Clearly you don't want this behavior. You want the behavior that Vue provides: takes an element with an id and mounts an app instead of it, which is permeable to outside styling and interference. It's just HTML. On top, it's smart enough to have scoped CSS.

Comment: There are only two valid cases where you'd want to use web components: when you want to mount inside a vue app developed with one major vue version components developed with another major version. And when you want CSS encapsulation. There's some debate over whether or not to use them if you use vue components inside Angular or React but, frankly, I think clean Vue components is still better for this last case. Why do you want to use them? And, to your question, there's no way to get past CSS encapsulation in web components. None. You need to load everything separately inside that namespace.

Comment: There is no barrier (or downside) on using independent Vue apps inside a vanilla app. They don't need to be custom elements. Also, if you have more than one, you should externalise Vue, rather than include it in each separate app/component. Consider reading [tips for a Vue Custom Elements Library](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/web-components.html#tips-for-a-vue-custom-elements-library)

Answer (score 1):

Custom elements defined using the Vue API always use a [`shadow DOM`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM), so they are isolated from the parent document and any global styles in the app.

So to make it happen, You can inject the bootstrap styles or any global style url's in the `styles` option by using `@import` statement.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const TestWidget = Vue.defineCustomElement({
  props: {
    id: String
  },
  data: () => {
    return {
      message: 'Test'
    }
  },
  template: `<div class="btn bg-info">{{id}} {{message}}</div>`,
  styles: [`@import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.css"); div { color: green; }`]
});

customElements.define('test-widget', TestWidget);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.css"/>
<div class="btn bg-info">Zero</div>
<test-widget id="One"></test-widget>
<test-widget id="Two"></test-widget>
```

Comment: Thank you, but @bassxzero already posted such proposal, but it does not solve the issue, please refer to description of bounty and comments under original post.

Comment: @Deele `but it does not solve the issue`  ? Can you please explain more about it. You want to access the global css styles in your custom element and it solves that problem.